# Unable to cast object of type ‘xxxx’ to type ‘Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.IPlugin’

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

Unable to cast object of type ‘xxxx’ to type ‘Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.IPlugin’ when trying to debug the error in plugin using plugin registration tool

We are using CRM on Premise

here is the full error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unable to cast object of type 'PluginCreatedBy.PluginCreatedByClass' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPlugin'.
Detail: <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <a:key>CallStack</a:key>
      <a:value i:type="b:string" xmlns:b="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   at PluginProfiler.Library.PluginAppDomainProxy.ExecuteCore(Stopwatch watch, ProfilerExecutionReport report, Object instance, Object executionParameter)
   at PluginProfiler.Library.AppDomainProxy.Execute(ProfilerExecutionConfiguration configuration, ProfilerExecutionReport report)</a:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>Unable to cast object of type 'PluginCreatedBy.PluginCreatedByClass' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPlugin'.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2021-07-19T05:18:55.850152Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Already tried adding version line in runtime tag of web.config

Comment: Which version of CRM do you use?

Comment: CRM 2011 On-Premise

Comment: The version of the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk .dll you used is 7.0.0.0, which fits CRM 2015. You should use .dlls of version 5.0.0.0 for the CRM 2011

Comment: you should post also the code of your plugin, this exception tells practically nothing